# Running specific set-up for tagged tests in JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm using JUnit 5 with Java to write integration tests. Some of them connect to the database and I'm looking for a way to both:

- filter tests out
- run the database set-up (truncate tables, etc.) before tests

for tests annotated with a specific annotation.

So far I've found that using tags lets me do the following:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;

@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Tag("database")
public @interface Database {}
```

and then use the `@Database` annotation to [filter annotated tests out](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-filter-tags).

Now I'm looking for a solution to hook up a test set-up for all tests annotated with this annotation. What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution requires two steps:

- Write a Jupiter extension e.g. `MyDatabaseSetup` that does the necessary setup/teardown work
- Add `@ExtendWith(MyDatabaseSetup.class)` to your Database annotation

Now every class or test method annotate with `@Database` will also use the extension.